# objc - How to create a listener with a "fail" and "success" methods

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a DataManager class and I want objects to be able to register to receive data.

In java I would have created a callback interface and pass it as a parameter to a method in the manager.

In objC, I understand there are several ways to "listen" to data (block, delegation, notification center, selector), and I was wondering which is best for what I want.

I need to be able to:

1. Store the listener (in case the data is not ready)
2. Add multiple listeners
3. Notify both error and sucess, and pass relevant data (in case of failure - a reason, and in case of success - the data)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add multiple listeners, NSNotificationCenter, is pretty easy and quick to set up:

Observe:

```
// Add this in viewDidLoad or init or something
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(receivedNotification:)
                                             name:@"YourNotificationKey"
                                           object:self];

// Receive this way
- (void) receivedNotification:(NSNotification *)note {
    NSLog(@"Received: %@", note.userInfo);

    if ([note.userInfo[@"success"]boolValue]) {
        // Successful
    }

    else {
        // Error
    }

}

// remove references
- (void) dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Send:

```
NSDictionary * data = @{@"some" : @"Random",
                        @"data" : @"here",
                        @"success": @YES};

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"YourNotificationKey" object:self userInfo:data];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have a questions though - wouldn't this be problematic if for some reason a register as an observer after the notification was sent? I can't make the assumption that the data is not ready yet

Comment: I'm assuming your DataManager is probably a singleton.  Maybe create a method that calls after you registered to check if data exists already?

Comment: If you register your class in the `init` method, then it should begin observing right away.  If the data exists before you instantiate your class, could you just pass the data to it?

Comment: It is a singleton. And I thought about that, but I wanted one method call to handle everything (and not one for getting data if available, and if not add observer or something). What do you say about passing an "onResult" block that ether returns data on success, or a failure reason enum on fail?

Comment: That sounds like it might be a cool solution.  You can save blocks as values in an array and call them when it's time.